# onBackPressed() is performing implemented action, but also exiting from app simultaneously

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement `onBackPressed()` with Fragment activity and i have achieved that with one interface.

This is implementation of `onBackPressed()` in MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragmentList != null) {
        if (resideMenu.isOpened()) {
            resideMenu.closeMenu();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
            if(fragment instanceof OnBackPressedListener){
                ((OnBackPressedListener)fragment).onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an implementation of interface in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
}
```

And this is the problem i'm getting when i try to use overrided `onBackPressed()` in Fragment:

`onBackPressed()` is activated and this `resideMenu` instance is opened, but it's not just opening this menu i wanted, it is also exiting the app as well.

Comment: In the else condition you have `super.onBackPressed();`, that will destroy your activity and exit the app if you don't have more activities

Comment: Are you managing well the interfaces and the hierarchy methods calling?

Comment: I think i do. So this is what is happening. When `onBackPressed` is called in fragment, the menu which i wanted to open is opened, but in the same time i'm leaving the app.